# How do I auto instantiate an object (singleton) in ASP.NET Web API v2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm loading a large object in memory into a singleton for reuse between GET requests.  However when the application starts I want the singleton to initialize automatically, currently I have something like this

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetData([FromBody]string text)
    {
        var spc = MySingleton.Instance; //runs some long instantiation process on the first call
        …
    }
```

So I have to wait until a request comes in before the singleton gets initialized.  Is there a way to make the singleton object initialize on its own when I start the application?

I tried putting this line

```
var spc = MySingleton.Instance;
```

In the Application_Start() method of global.asax.cs but it didn't do anything.

Comment: I would suggest looking into doing a standard IIS Warm Up application procedure, like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization This will also help when you need to recycle your application pool, and IIS can overlap the initialization of a second instance before shutting down the first instance.

Comment: @RobertMcKee thanks, I think that is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Trying use Dependency Injection, hopefully the IOC container will create your configured instance of the singleton object before your first request.

In `Startup.cs`, in the `ConfigureServices` method you will add something like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ISingleton, Singleton>();
}
```

From this [Singleton pattern tutorial here](https://espressocoder.com/2019/01/03/implementing-the-singleton-pattern-in-asp-net-core/).

In your controller that has the method `GetData` you will change the default constructor from parameter-less to having the Singleton object be a required argument to instantiate that controller. The .NET Core IOC container will take care of instantiating the controller passing your singleton instance configured in in `Startup.ConfigureServices`.